# Calling java agent from lotus formula

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-formula

I am trying to call a java agent from lotus formula code.

```
@Command( [RunAgent] ; MyJavaAgent );
```

But when a formula is executed I get an error prompt saying:

```
Internal Error processing command:incorrect number of parameters.
```

I am clueless about this error, because my java agent code isn't expecting any parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call your agent with

```
@Command( [RunAgent] ; "MyJavaAgent" );
```

The second parameter has to be a string: agent's name.

`MyJavaAgent` without the quotation marks gets interpreted as a field or variable. As such a field or variable is not defined it will be rated as an empty value "". The resulting
`@Command([RunAgent]; "")` throws exactly the error you mentioned.

So, your agent wasn't called yet and error was thrown in @Command itself.